# What's the difference between from . import and import?

Tags: python, import

What is the difference between:

```
from . import spam
```

and:

```
import spam
```

?

Also, what's the requirement to *not* have errors with the first import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from . import spam` searches for module `spam` in the current (same level) package. For instance, if you have package like this:

```
mypackage
   __init__.py
   foo.py
   spam.py
```

, inside `foo.py`, you can import `spam` by using `from . import spam`.

`import spam` searches for module `spam` in the module search path defined as a list `sys.path`. For instance, `spam` could be a builtin module, or the one you install using `pip`.

Comment: What is `mypackage`? What differs it from a regular folder?

Comment: `mypackage` is just a name for the package. The difference here is the file `__init__.py`. It's a convention that every folder contains that file, even just an empty one, is considered as a Python package. `foo.py`, `spam.py` are modules in this package.

Comment: Are you certain these are all the requirements? When I create a folder named `mypackage` with empty `__init__.py` and `spam.py` and with `from . import spam` as the sole line for `foo.py` it raises `ImportError: cannot import name 'spam'`.

Comment: Are you running `python foo.py` directly? If it's true, it's an expected behavior since you are running it as standalone module. It isn't aware of the package. But if you have a `main.py` in the same level as `mypackage`, you can `from mypackage import foo`.

Comment: I tried that and it worked, thanks for all the help. So the script with `from . import spam` needs to be `import`ed, or otherwise used, from a higher directory than itself?

Comment: Yes it must be in a "package context", so either you need to import it from a higher level directory, or you distribute entire `mypackage` as a third party package.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do in the first one is: from the current working directory of your python script, you are trying to import a module. In the old days "." means the current directory (it still means that now if you use terminal :D ). This is pointless, as python already scans your current directory  (or folder) for an importable module if it can't find one in site-packages. I'd stick to the second one (as it means the same thing.)

Comment: The system is really directory based

Comment: yes, looking at @dvnguyen 's question, this feature is infact useful when developing packages

Comment: *it means the same thing* — not really, the resolution order is different, which might be important.